# Linkedin API how to get company status updates? python

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I looked at other questions like this, but none seem to help me. I am trying to get only the status updates for a company. Currently, it only gets the job updates which makes things very confusing. Also, the count function does not work because I always get the same answer. Please see below.

code:

```
CONSUMER_KEY = '9puxXXXXXXXXX'     # This is api_key
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'brtXXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is secret_key

USER_TOKEN = '3fb22a2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is oauth_token
USER_SECRET = '3b0c7feXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'   # This is oauth_secret
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

from linkedin import linkedin
from oauthlib import *

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                                      USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                                      RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

d = application.get_company_updates(1035, params={'count': 1})
e = application.get_company_products(1035, params={'count': 10})
print d
print ''
print 'BOTH e AND d GIVE THE SAME ANSWER????' 
print ''
print e
```

When you run this, both "e" and "d" will just return 10 job updates. please do not write the answer as

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?event-type=status-update
```

that does not help me at all. I need a working python code sample, not a website. Thank you

Comment: Figured it out. It was because the 10 posts were all job updates and not status updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkedin API only gives 10 updates at a time. The updates were all job updates and none were status updates.